# Chef manage running on Amazon Linux but not accessible. Security group ports are open

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am trying to fix some errors with my chef server install. I followed the documentation on chef's website and chef server did install, however I am unable to access the server's UI (user interface). I opened all the ports to my AWS instance in my security groups settings but this still didn't allow me to access the UI. I've attached the shell script for the install, along with console output from the commands I used to try and diagnose the problem. I am uncertain on what steps I should take next and would appreciate some assistance. Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do your provisioning here"
sudo wget https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef-server/12.14.0/el/7/chef-server-core-12.14.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ./chef-server-core-12.14.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-server-ctl user-create joeygrimm Joey Grimm jgrimm@example.com 'password' --filename ~/chef.admin.pem
sudo chef-server-ctl org-create example 'example' --association_user joeygrimm --filename ~/chef.org.pem
sudo chef-server-ctl install chef-manage
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-manage-ctl reconfigure --accept-license
sudo chef-server-ctl install opscode-push-jobs-server
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo opscode-push-jobs-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-server-ctl install opscode-reporting
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo opscode-reporting-ctl reconfigure
sudo mkdir /etc/opscode && sudo touch /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
openssl genrsa -des3 -out chef_server.key 2048
openssl rsa -in chef_server.key -out chef_server.key.insecure
mv chef_server.key chef_server.key.secure
mv chef_server.key.insecure chef_server.key
openssl req -new -key chef_server.key -out chef_server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in chef_server.csr -signkey chef_server.key -out chef_server.crt
rm chef_server.key
mv chef_server.key.secure /var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef_server.key
mv chef_server.csr /var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef_server.csr
mv chef_server.crt /var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef_server.crt
export CHEF_HOST_NAME=`hostname -f`
echo "api_fqdn = \"${CHEF_HOST_NAME}\"" > /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
echo "nginx['ssl_certificate'] = \"/var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef-server.crt\"" >> /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
echo "nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = \"/var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef-server.key\"" >> /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
echo "nginx['server_name'] = \"${CHEF_HOST_NAME}\"" >> /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Console Output 1: ps aux | grep chef
This command was done to establish that chef and chef-manage were running.

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-252 opscode]$ ps aux | grep chef
root      8812  0.0  0.0   4192  1128 ?        Ss   21:31   0:00 runsv opscode-erchef
root      9215  0.0  0.0   4192   720 ?        Ss   21:31   0:00 runsv opscode-chef-mover
opscode  10418  0.0  0.0   4336  1160 ?        S    21:36   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/opscode-erchef
opscode  10653  0.0  0.0   4336   644 ?        S    21:36   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/opscode-chef-mover
root     17285  0.0  0.0   4340  1088 ?        Ss   21:38   0:00 runsvdir -P /opt/chef-manage/service log: ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
root     17796  0.0  0.0   4332   684 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/bin/svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-manage/redis
opscode  17798  0.3  4.0 1331300 162524 ?      Ssl  21:38   0:05 sidekiq 2.5.2 chef-manage [0 of 25 busy]                                
opscode  17810  0.2  3.4 556484 140016 ?       Ssl  21:38   0:04 unicorn master -E production -c /var/opt/chef-manage/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config.ru
root     17815  0.0  0.0   4332  1204 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/bin/svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-manage/web
root     17824  0.0  0.0   4332  1200 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/bin/svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-manage/worker
opscode  17888  0.0  3.3 556484 134684 ?       Sl   21:38   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -E production -c /var/opt/chef-manage/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config.ru
opscode  17891  0.0  3.3 556484 134796 ?       Sl   21:38   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -E production -c /var/opt/chef-manage/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config.ru
opscode  21449  0.4  1.7 326820 71056 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:07 /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/erts-7.3/bin/beam.smp -Bd -K true -A 5 -- -root /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef -progname opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/bin/oc_erchef -- -home /var/opt/opscode/opscode-erchef -- -noshell -noshell -noinput -boot /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/releases/12.14.0+20170330124015/oc_erchef -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib -config /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/sys.config -name erchef@127.0.0.1 -setcookie erchef -smp enable -pa lib/patches -pa -- foreground
497      21940  0.0  0.2 1097176 9460 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(43608) idle               
497      21941  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(36951) idle               
497      21942  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(46012) idle               
497      21943  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(36683) idle               
497      21957  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(60976) idle               
497      21965  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(35814) idle               
497      21967  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(38066) idle               
497      21968  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(56560) idle               
497      21974  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(46388) idle               
497      21978  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(54068) idle               
497      21979  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(33891) idle               
497      21980  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(57451) idle               
497      21981  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(51465) idle               
497      21982  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(46897) idle               
497      21983  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(33646) idle               
497      21984  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(51748) idle               
497      21985  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(52418) idle               
497      21986  0.0  0.2 1097176 9096 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(39103) idle               
497      21987  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(47556) idle               
497      21988  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(52778) idle               
opscode  21989  0.0  0.5 116684 24144 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  21996  0.0  0.5 116704 24236 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  21998  0.0  0.5 116692 24104 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  22000  0.0  0.5 116696 24248 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  22011  0.0  0.5 116680 24196 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
ec2-user 31318  0.0  0.0 110460  2200 pts/0    S+   22:06   0:00 grep --color=auto chef
```

Console Output 2: netstat -anp | grep "LISTEN" and "LISTENING"
grep for what ports were listening and to see if port 80 was open.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-252 opscode]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep "LISTENING"
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21536  9759/postgres       /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8009   1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8060   1555/udevd          @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9194   2285/rpcbind        /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9758   2337/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-252 opscode]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep "LISTEN"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9463              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21330/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34520             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21330/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15672             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9639/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9759/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2563/sendmail
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11002             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17764/redis-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:16379             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27989/redis-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37788             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21449/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46014             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21405/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21449/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4321              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21405/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21392/rails master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5672              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9639/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25672             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9639/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46637               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2306/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38862             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22173/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2285/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22173/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4369              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2996/epmd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22173/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22173/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9462              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17810/unicorn maste
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2533/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8983       :::*                        LISTEN      10029/java
tcp        0      0 :::58455                    :::*                        LISTEN      2306/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      2285/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 ::1:4369                    :::*                        LISTEN      2996/epmd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2533/sshd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21536  9759/postgres       /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8009   1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8060   1555/udevd          @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9194   2285/rpcbind        /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9758   2337/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

Console Output 3

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-252 opscode]$ ps aux | grep chef
root      8812  0.0  0.0   4192  1128 ?        Ss   21:31   0:00 runsv opscode-erchef
root      9215  0.0  0.0   4192   720 ?        Ss   21:31   0:00 runsv opscode-chef-mover
opscode  10418  0.0  0.0   4336  1160 ?        S    21:36   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/opscode-erchef
opscode  10653  0.0  0.0   4336   644 ?        S    21:36   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/opscode-chef-mover
root     17285  0.0  0.0   4340  1088 ?        Ss   21:38   0:00 runsvdir -P /opt/chef-manage/service log: ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
root     17796  0.0  0.0   4332   684 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/bin/svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-manage/redis
opscode  17798  0.2  4.0 1332068 164108 ?      Ssl  21:38   0:05 sidekiq 2.5.2 chef-manage [0 of 25 busy]                                
opscode  17810  0.2  3.4 556484 140016 ?       Ssl  21:38   0:04 unicorn master -E production -c /var/opt/chef-manage/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config.ru
root     17815  0.0  0.0   4332  1204 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/bin/svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-manage/web
root     17824  0.0  0.0   4332  1200 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/bin/svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-manage/worker
opscode  17888  0.0  3.3 556484 134684 ?       Sl   21:38   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -E production -c /var/opt/chef-manage/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config.ru
opscode  17891  0.0  3.3 556484 134796 ?       Sl   21:38   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -E production -c /var/opt/chef-manage/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/config.ru
opscode  21449  0.4  1.7 329388 71068 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:07 /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/erts-7.3/bin/beam.smp -Bd -K true -A 5 -- -root /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef -progname opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/bin/oc_erchef -- -home /var/opt/opscode/opscode-erchef -- -noshell -noshell -noinput -boot /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/releases/12.14.0+20170330124015/oc_erchef -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib -config /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/sys.config -name erchef@127.0.0.1 -setcookie erchef -smp enable -pa lib/patches -pa -- foreground
497      21940  0.0  0.2 1097176 9460 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(43608) idle               
497      21941  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(36951) idle               
497      21942  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(46012) idle               
497      21943  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(36683) idle               
497      21957  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(60976) idle               
497      21965  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(35814) idle               
497      21967  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(38066) idle               
497      21968  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(56560) idle               
497      21974  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(46388) idle               
497      21978  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(54068) idle               
497      21979  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(33891) idle               
497      21980  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(57451) idle               
497      21981  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(51465) idle               
497      21982  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(46897) idle               
497      21983  0.0  0.2 1097176 9084 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(33646) idle               
497      21984  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(51748) idle               
497      21985  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(52418) idle               
497      21986  0.0  0.2 1097176 9096 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(39103) idle               
497      21987  0.0  0.2 1097176 9092 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(47556) idle               
497      21988  0.0  0.2 1097176 9088 ?        Ss   21:39   0:00 postgres: opscode_chef opscode_chef 127.0.0.1(52778) idle               
opscode  21989  0.0  0.5 116684 24144 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  21996  0.0  0.5 116704 24236 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  21998  0.0  0.5 116692 24104 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  22000  0.0  0.5 116696 24248 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
opscode  22011  0.0  0.5 116680 24196 ?        Ssl  21:39   0:00 ruby /opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/lib/chef_objects-12.14.0+20170330124015/priv/depselector_rb/depselector.rb
ec2-user 31523  0.0  0.0 110460  2136 pts/0    S+   22:07   0:00 grep --color=auto chef
```

Console Output 4: sudo cat /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
This is to show the contents of the chef-server.rb file

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-252 opscode]$ sudo cat /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
api_fqdn = "ip-172-31-17-252.us-west-2.compute.internal"
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef-server.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/chef-server.key"
nginx['server_name'] = "ip-172-31-17-252.us-west-2.compute.internal"
```

Console Output 5: This is my chef-server-running.json informationI My

https://gist.github.com/joeygrimm/b9515eecc1e470fcb75d13fe6facfa3c

Comment: What port did you open? Unless doing a complex HA configuration all you need is 22 and 443.

Answer (score 1):

So you got most of it right - but did you put it behind an Elastic IP or some other kind of public IP?
how do you intend to reach it over public internet?

at the end of the day you need to know what that is...

```
server_name = "MY_PUBLIC_IP_HERE"
api_fqdn server_name
nginx['url'] = "https://#{server_name}"
nginx['server_name'] = server_name
lb['fqdn'] = server_name
bookshelf['vip'] = server_name
```

you may need to look at those values in /etc/chef-server/  as you need to configure it not for the host its on in ec2 but the IP it will respond on (public elastic IP address)

hope it helps